# How to exclude patterns in regex conditionally in bash?

Tags: regex, bash, grep

This is the content of input.txt:

```
hello=123
1234
stack=(23(4))
12341234
overflow=345
=
friends=(987)
```

Then I'm trying to match all the lines with equal removing the external parenteses (if the line has it).

To be clear, **this is the result I'm looking for**:

```
hello=123
stack=23(4)
overflow=345
friends=987
```

I toughth in something like this:

```
cat input.txt | grep -Poh '.+=(?=\()?.+(?=\))?'
```

But does not returns nothing. What am I doing wrong? Do you have any idea to do this? I'm so interested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using awk:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="="} NF==2 && $1!=""{gsub(/^\(|\)$/, "", $2); print}' file
hello=123
stack=23(4)
overflow=345
friends=987
```

Comment: Thanks! And could I do the same with regex?

Comment: This is regex that is being used in `gsub`. My grep doesn't support `-P` (Mac)

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternate way with `sed`:

```
sed -nr '              # Use n to disable default printing and r for extended regex 
/.+=.+/ {              # Look for lines with key value pairs separated by =
    /[(]/!ba;          # If the line does not contain a paren branch out to label a
    s/\(([^)]+)\)/\1/; # If the line contains a paren find a subset and print that
    :a                 # Our label 
    p                  # print the line
}' file
```

```
$ sed -nr '/.+=.+/{/[(]/!ba;s/\(([^)]+)\)/\1/;:a;p}' file
hello=123
stack=23(4)
overflow=345
friends=987
```